# Import { __extends } from "tslib" SyntaxError : Unexpected token

Tags: angular, ionic4

I integrate the SSR in my project and the build works but when I launch the build there is this Error

```
> hibou@0.0.1 serve:ssr /home/nomentsafidy/Desktop/gmp/apps/hibou
> node dist/app/server/main.js

/home/nomentsafidy/Desktop/gmp/apps/hibou/node_modules/@ionic-native/status-bar/ngx/index.js:1
import { __extends } from "tslib";
       ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:872:18)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:947:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:703:12)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:830:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:68:18)
    at Object.b3Iw (/home/nomentsafidy/Desktop/gmp/apps/hibou/dist/app/server/main.js:1:95673)
    at __webpack_require__ (/home/nomentsafidy/Desktop/gmp/apps/hibou/dist/app/server/main.js:1:317)
    at Module.uj+Y (/home/nomentsafidy/Desktop/gmp/apps/hibou/dist/app/server/main.js:1:481177)
    at __webpack_require__ (/home/nomentsafidy/Desktop/gmp/apps/hibou/dist/app/server/main.js:1:317)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! hibou@0.0.1 serve:ssr: `node dist/app/server/main.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the hibou@0.0.1 serve:ssr script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/nomentsafidy/.npm/_logs/2021-05-04T12_14_08_449Z-debug.log
```

here is the content of my tsconfig.json

```
{
    "compileOnSave": false,
    "compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": "./",
        "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "declaration": false,
        "module": "esnext",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "importHelpers": true,
        "target": "es2015",
        "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types"],
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "lib": ["es2018", "dom"],
        "paths": {
            "hibou-lib": ["../../dist/hibou-lib"],
            "hibou-lib/*": ["../../dist/hibou-lib/*"],
            "@angular/*": ["../node_modules/@angular/*"]
        }
    },
    "angularCompilerOptions": {
        "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true,
        "strictInjectionParameters": true
    }
}
```

my tsconfig.server.json

```
/* To learn more about this file see: https://angular.io/config/tsconfig. */
{
    "extends": "./tsconfig.app.json",
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "./out-tsc/server",
        "target": "es2015",
        "types": ["node"]
    },
    "files": ["src/main.server.ts", "server.ts"],
    "angularCompilerOptions": {
        "entryModule": "./src/app/app.server.module#AppServerModule"
    }
}
```

I tried to build it with node 10.14.0 12.10.0 14.16.1 but I have the same issue

the version of tslib in the package.json is ^ 1.6.1

Comment: please add code snippets as code and not as a screenshot

Comment: Ok. i will do it now